# Can I plant PawPaw tree close to concrete fence?

Tags: trees

Can I plant Paw Paw three close to my concrete fence? Are the roots going to distruction the concrete fence?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the roots are not invasive.   I have had them right next to the house (like the trunk touching the wall) with no ill effect to the tree or the house.

Here's someone that concurs

> **Are pawpaw roots invasive?**
>
> The Pawpaw, or Papaya tree (Carica papaya), is best known for its delicious fruit. But to have fruit, you’re going to need two of these trees as they are not self-pollinators. The good thing is that their root structure is not invasive, so they’re a good choice for planting near a home, driveway, or septic drain field.

[What Type Of Root System Does Pawpaw Have?](https://sweetishhill.com/what-type-of-root-system-does-pawpaw-have/)

I am not associated with the website, its just the first one that I found.